# Why break does not exit map loop properly?

Tags: java, list

I have code in the spring batch job that does the validation in the processor. So I try to check if the data from the file is matching what is in dB. If not matching should print a log error. So I put a condition where if the data match, the loop should exit. However, when the data match, the loop occurs two times instead of going to the next code. May help me with this?

***Processor***

```
 public OtherSellerData process(OtherSellerData otherSellerData) {
        
        for (String sellerId : seller) {
            boolean rountingNumberFlag = false;
            //check duplication
            if (! sellerId.equals(otherSellerData.getSellerId())) {
                
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> otherBankSeller : branchBank.entrySet()) {
                    if (otherBankSeller.getKey().equals(otherSellerData.getSellerBank())) {
                        otherSellerData.setSellerBank(otherBankSeller.getValue());
                        rountingNumberFlag = true;
                    break;
                    }
                }

                LOGGER.info(String.valueOf(rountingNumberFlag));
                //routing number not match from database
                if (! rountingNumberFlag){
                    LOGGER.error("The routing number "
                            + otherSellerData.getSellerBank()
                            + " does not exist in database");
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                LOGGER.info("Seller ID "
                        + sellerId
                        + " already existed in database.");
                return null;
            }
        }
        return otherSellerData;
```

***Log***

```
2020-12-05 11:43:30.588  INFO 16220 --- [           main] n.t.r.d.o.s.processor.CustomValidation   : true
2020-12-05 11:43:30.588  INFO 16220 --- [           main] n.t.r.d.o.s.processor.CustomValidation   : DD00000040
2020-12-05 11:43:30.588  INFO 16220 --- [           main] n.t.r.d.o.s.processor.CustomValidation   : false
2020-12-05 11:43:30.588  INFO 16220 --- [           main] n.t.r.d.o.s.processor.CustomValidation   : DD00000040
2020-12-05 11:43:30.588 ERROR 16220 --- [           main] n.t.r.d.o.s.processor.CustomValidation   : The routing number PUBLIC BANK does not exist in database
2020-12-05 11:43:30.590  INFO 16220 --- [           main] n.t.r.d.o.s.processor.CustomValidation   : true
2020-12-05 11:43:30.590  INFO 16220 --- [           main] n.t.r.d.o.s.processor.CustomValidation   : DD00000041
2020-12-05 11:43:30.590  INFO 16220 --- [           main] n.t.r.d.o.s.processor.CustomValidation   : false
2020-12-05 11:43:30.590  INFO 16220 --- [           main] n.t.r.d.o.s.processor.CustomValidation   : DD00000041
2020-12-05 11:43:30.590 ERROR 16220 --- [           main] n.t.r.d.o.s.processor.CustomValidation   : The routing number PUBLIC BANK does not exist in database
2020-12-05 11:43:30.592  INFO 16220 --- [           main] n.t.r.d.o.s.processor.CustomValidation   : false
2020-12-05 11:43:30.592  INFO 16220 --- [           main] n.t.r.d.o.s.processor.CustomValidation   : DD00000042
2020-12-05 11:43:30.592 ERROR 16220 --- [           main] n.t.r.d.o.s.processor.CustomValidation   : The routing number 100002296 does not exist in database
2020-12-05 11:43:30.594  INFO 16220 --- [           main] n.t.r.d.o.s.processor.CustomValidation   : false
2020-12-05 11:43:30.594  INFO 16220 --- [           main] n.t.r.d.o.s.processor.CustomValidation   : DD00000043
2020-12-05 11:43:30.594 ERROR 16220 --- [           main] n.t.r.d.o.s.processor.CustomValidation   : The routing number 100002296 does not exist in database
2020-12-05 11:43:30.596  INFO 16220 --- [           main] n.t.r.d.o.s.processor.CustomValidation   : false
2020-12-05 11:43:30.596  INFO 16220 --- [           main] n.t.r.d.o.s.processor.CustomValidation   : DD00000044
2020-12-05 11:43:30.596 ERROR 16220 --- [           main] n.t.r.d.o.s.processor.CustomValidation   : The routing number 100002296 does not exist in database
```

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code statement by statement in a debugger? What does it tell you?

Comment: A `break` statement only exits the loop that immediately surrounds it.  That is, a `break` in a loop that's nested in another loop only exits the _inner_ loop; the outer loop continues to execute.  If you want to exit from both loops, you need other arrangements, such as a **labelled break** ([JLS sec. 14.15](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15)

Comment: Can you explain? I put the ```LOGGER.info(String.valueOf(rountingNumberFlag));``` just to check if ```if``` statment run correctly or not. when the ```rountingNumberFlag``` is false, it run once, but when ```rountingNumberFlag``` is true, if run twice. Please check log

Comment: but you also call proces in a loop probably? Because you have a return after the if (! rountingNumberFlag){ ... but still get messages afterwards